# How to Visible and InVisible RelativeLayout through Checkbox in android studio Java?

Tags: android

I have two RelativeLayout on a page with some textboxes in them. I want to show this RelativeLayout with the help of two checkboxes. I mean when the first check box is clicked then the first RelativeLayout is shown and when the second check box is clicked the RelativeLayout view is shown and the first relative is hidden.I have using following code in layout.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/textborder"
            android:id="@+id/badirelative">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/badiimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="310dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />


           
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:background="@drawable/textborder"
                        android:id="@+id/ba11"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/purple_500" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:background="@drawable/textborder"
                        android:id="@+id/ba8"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/purple_500" />
                  

                </LinearLayout>
        

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the checkbox code.When i click the checkbox then app close.Where is the error in my code, can someone check and tell me?

```
     //Check box1(Atashi) Value start hare>>>>>>>>>>
    atashi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
  atshirelative.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
   }

    });
```

Comment: where is your check boxes

Comment: I haven't uploaded the code for the check boxes in the question due to length but I have used them above RelativeLayout .

Comment: Please clearly explain your question ? I think you want to show RelativeLayout through Check boxes,. When you click first check  box then it show first RelativeLayout hide second RelativeLayout and when you click second check box then it show second RelativeLayout and hide first RelativeLayout.، Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, you have understood correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your XML Layout.

```
           <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sss6"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <CheckBox
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/check1"
               android:text="Check 1
               android:textSize="14sp">
           </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/check2"
                android:text="Check 2"
                android:textSize="14sp">
            </CheckBox>
         
        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

This is for RelativeLayout. Remember use GONE if you want to show or hide more than one RelativeLayout.

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/textborder"
            android:id="@+id/relative1">

         
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/at1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:background="@drawable/textborder"
                        android:id="@+id/box8"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/purple_500" />
               </LinerLlayout>
            </LinerLayout>
          </RelativeLayout>
```

This is Second RelativeLayout.

```
             <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/textborder"
            android:id="@+id/relative2">

         
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/at1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:background="@drawable/textborder"
                        android:id="@+id/box8"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/purple_500" />
                         </LinerLlayout>
                     </LinerLayout>
                 </RelativeLayout>
```

In your Java use such as .....

```
        CheckBox check1, check2;
           RelativeLayout relative1,relative2;


       setContentView(R.layout.activity_total_square_naqoosh);
  
              check1 = findViewById(R.id.check1);
           check2 = findViewById(R.id.check2);
  
           relative1 = findViewById(R.id.relative1);
            relative2 = findViewById(R.id.relative2);

         //Check box1 code start hare>>>>>>>>>>
       check1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          if (check1.isChecked()) {
                        check2.setChecked(false);
                       
                        relative1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        relative2.setVisibility(relative2.GONE);
                }
                    }

               });

         //Check box2 code start hare>>>>>>>>>>
                check2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             if (check2.isChecked()) {
                        check1.setChecked(false);
                       
                        relative2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        relative1.setVisibility(relative1.GONE);
            }
        }

               });
```

Comment: Well, i have done. Your answer is correct.